# What progress has been made on the Collatz conjecture since Crandall's 1978 paper?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, collatz-conjecture

I have recently read the famous paper by [Crandall (1978)](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-144/S0025-5718-1978-0480321-3/S0025-5718-1978-0480321-3.pdf) on the $3x+1$ problem, and I wonder what progress has been made since then.

The paper claims that:

1. If a cycle exists, then the minimum number of $3x+1$ steps for the number to reach itself is $17985$. Is there a better lower bound nowadays?
2. It is not known whether a positive density of odd integers satisfy the conjecture. Is that still unknown?

Comment: Terrence Tao has come incredibly close to proving it without proving it. Here is his recent paper. https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03562

Comment: Cycle length is known to be at least 114 billion -- [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Cycle_length).

Comment: @EricTowers So the lower bound is about $10^{11}$. Did I interprete "billion" correctly ?

Comment: @Peter : Yes.  Although one could have obtained that answer more quickly by following the reference.

Comment: That with the density should be known. It is known that the counterexamples (if there are any) form an extremely tiny set.

Comment: I wonder about the progress that has been made concerning possible divergent trajectories.

Comment: @EricTowers Wikipedia doesn't show how the 114 billion number is obtained. The reference Eliahou (1993) explicitly obtains the 17,087,915 lower bound, but I couldn't find an exlicit formula for generalizing this result.

Comment: @bluewhale Even this bound is much better than the older bound :)

Comment: @Peter sure thing!

Comment: [Eliahou et al. 2021](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.11160.pdf) has this at the bottom of p. 3, referencing the same 1993 paper and Barina's explicit verification to $2^{68}$.

Comment: In fact, Barin [reports](https://pcbarina.fit.vutbr.cz/) that Collatz is confirmed up to $2^{69}$ (about a month ago).  My read of the 1993 paper is that this doesn't move the lower bound (but I skimmed very quickly, so could have missed something important).

Comment: I do note the 114 billion number is $p_{21,1}$ in table 2 in the 1993 paper.

Comment: Thanks for the additional references, @EricTowers. So the procedure seems to be to pick the first row where tr(n,i) > N in that table and look at the value of p_(n,i) in that row, where N is the number up to which the conjecture has been verified. Fair enough

Comment: @Peter UK billion used to be $10^{12}$ whereas nowadays it matches the US billion $10^{9}$

Comment: Here is a MSE Q&A, where the new Barina-limit is used/discussed in connection with the three-coefficients-formula : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4616340

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Further_reading

Answer (score 7):

As of the date of this post the conjecture has been [confirmed](https://pcbarina.fit.vutbr.cz/) to be true up to $$682 \times 2^{60}\left(\approx 2^{69.41}\right).$$

In terms of proving it Terence Tao published a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03562) titled "Almost all orbits of the Collatz map attain almost bounded values."

"Almost all"! How exciting is that! But who knows, maybe we are still further than we think...