# What is the minimum nontrivial cycle length in the Collatz problem?

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Recently, I have read the article (Eliahou, 1993).
The author shows that any nontrivial cycle must contain at least 17 087 915 elements, assuming that the Collatz problem has been verified up to $2^{40}$.
To find this out, Eliahou set up the equation
$$
\operatorname{Card}\Omega = 301\,994a + 17\,087\,915b + 85\,137\,581c\text{,}
$$
where $a, b, c$ are nonnegative integers, $b>0$, and $ac=0$.
My first question is: How did he arrive at this equation?
And the second question: How can I construct such an equation for [the current boundary](https://pcbarina.fit.vutbr.cz/) $662 \times 2^{60}$? I [saw a similar equation](https://www.mathematics.pitt.edu/sites/default/files/Martiny%2020-min-grad.pdf) for the boundary $1.08 \times 2^{60}$, but I don't know how they came up with it.

#### References

(Eliahou, 1993) Shalom Eliahou. The 3x+1 problem: new lower bounds on nontrivial cycle lengths. Discrete Mathematics, volume 118, issues 1–3, pages 45-56, 1993. https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(93)90052-U

Comment: Doesn't the article itself contain information about that equation?

Comment: The coefficients at $(a,b,c)$ can be found in the convergents of the continued fraction of $\log_2(3)$: $$ \small \begin{array} {r} 
 S & N \\ \hline
 1 & 1 \\ 
 2 & 1 \\ 
 3 & 2 \\ 
 8 & 5 \\ 
 19 & 12 \\ 
 ... & ... \\ 
 176251 & 111202 \\ 
 301994 & 190537 \\ 
 16785921 & 10590737 \\ 
 17087915 & 10781274 \\ 
 85137581 & 53715833 \\ 
 272500658 & 171928773 \\ 
 ... & ...
 \end{array} $$ However, as well I don't yet know how the argument has been developed ...

Comment: To make it simple (and approximative), when x is very large, $3x+1$ is very close to $3x$ ; so if we have a cycle, we have to integers $m$ and $n$ , with $\frac{3^m/2^n}=1+ \varepsilon$ ; if x is larger than $N$, $\varepsilon$ should be less than $1/N$ ; The couples (m,n) that match this criteria are ''easy'' to determine.

Comment: $\frac{3^m}{2^n}=1+ \varepsilon$ ... ...  So a cycle should contain at least $17 087 915$ elements, but we can even say it should contain exactly $17 087 915$ elements, or exactly $85 137 581$ elements

Comment: @Lourrran - well, between that shown "(common) convergents" there are the so-called "generalized" or "incomplete convergents"; they are not often mentioned, but are "in the same right" as the "common convergents". For the given case it showed to be meaningful to make the lower bound for a possible cycle more precise by looking at such "generalized convergents" (see my exchange with Collag3n below his answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for Eliahou, but from [Simons m-cycles](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228846209_Theoretical_and_computational_bounds_for_m-cycles_of_the_3n_1_problem) which also use convergents of continued fractions

$K>$ min$\{q_n,\frac{2\cdot x_{min}}{q_n+q_{n+1}}\}$

with $x_{min}=662\cdot2^{60}$ you would get $K>\frac{2\cdot x_{min}}{q_{22}+q_{23}}$ ($q_{22}=65470613321$ $q_{23}=137528045312$)

$K>7.519.596.840$
$\operatorname{Card}\Omega>11.918.279.012$

To find the right $q_n$ just search for the minimum one satisfying $x_{min}<\frac{q_n(q_n+q_{n+1})}{2}$ and verify that $q_{n-1}<\frac{2\cdot x_{min}}{q_n+q_{n+1}}$ (if not, pick $q_{n-1}$)

The $\operatorname{Card}\Omega$ equation is just using properties of consecutives convergents (Farey properties) and use those consecutive $q_n$ to determine a "minimal form" it would have.

(I forgot to mention but as mentioned by Gottfried and Eliahou, these are convergents of $\log_2(3)$)

**EDIT:**

Eliahou seems to give larger bounds

$\frac{p_{23}}{q_{23}}<\log_2(3+\frac{1}{662\cdot 2^{60}})<\frac{p_{21}}
{q_{21}}$

($\frac{p_{21}}
{q_{21}}$ being the smallest convergent larger than the center term, or in other word having the largest index $n$ while still being larger than the center term)

It would mean $\operatorname{Card}\Omega\geq p_{23}=217.976.794.617$

Note that odd indexes gives convergents larger than $\log_2(3)$ and even indexes are smaller. $\operatorname{Card}\Omega$ would be constructed with $p_{21}$, $p_{23}$ and $p_{24}$ (but only $p_{23}$ is "guaranteed")

Didn't read that paper yet...I know what to read next now

**EDIT2:**

I think I should definitely read the paper before posting (which I still didn't do!!). Thanks Gottfried for the tip, indeed $\{\frac{p_{21}}{q_{21}},\frac{p_{23}}{q_{23}}\}$ are not Farey pairs like $\{\frac{p_{13}}{q_{13}},\frac{p_{15}}{q_{15}}\}$ or $\{\frac{p_{19}}{q_{19}},\frac{p_{21}}{q_{21}}\}$ and we can't use the $\frac{p}{q}<\frac{ap+bp'}{aq+bq'}<\frac{p'} {q'}$ property, so we need to look at the intermediate/generalized convergents too, especially what Eliahou call "Upper convergents".

The next "Upper convergent" after $\frac{p_{21}}{q_{21}}$ is not $\frac{p_{23}}{q_{23}}$, but $\frac{p_{21,1}}{q_{21,1}}$ (The one indicated by Gottfried, and in Table 2 from the paper).

So we end up with this inequality (after ensuring that $|p_nq_{n+1}-p_{n+1}q_n|=1$ for consecutive fractions):

$\frac{p_{22}}{q_{22}}<\log_2(3)<\frac{p_{21,1}}{q_{21,1}}<\log_2(3+\frac{1}{662\cdot 2^{60}})<\frac{p_{21}}{q_{21}}$

and with $\log_2(3)<\frac{\operatorname{Card}\Omega}{K}<\log_2(3+\frac{1}{662\cdot 2^{60}})$ we have 3 posibilities:

$\frac{p_{22}}{q_{22}}<\frac{\operatorname{Card}\Omega}{K}<\frac{p_{21,1}} {q_{21,1}}$ or $\frac{\operatorname{Card}\Omega}{K}=\frac{p_{21,1}} {q_{21,1}}$ or $\frac{p_{21,1}}{q_{21,1}}<\frac{\operatorname{Card}\Omega}{K}<\frac{p_{21}} {q_{21}}$

By applying $\frac{p}{q}<\frac{ap+bp'}{aq+bq'}<\frac{p'} {q'}$ we get

$\operatorname{Card}\Omega\geq p_{21,1}=114.208.327.604$

Sorry for the mess...I originally had no intention to comment on Eliahou but couldn't resist to take a peak

Comment: Hm, I'm still not fluent with Eliahou's arguing. But in the formula after the "EDIT:"-clause: there are *generalized* convergents in between $(p,q)_{21}$ and $(p,q)_{23}$ which might satisfy the numerical evaluation with even sharper bounds... Is there some thought about that?

Comment: @Gottried Helms, I didn't read the full paper, but I think the argument seems to be around these convergents in between.  $\frac{p_{24}}{q_{24}}<\frac{\operatorname{Card}\Omega}{K}<\frac{p_{21}}
{q_{21}}$ is split in 3 possibilities: $\frac{p_{24}}{q_{24}}<\frac{\operatorname{Card}\Omega}{K}<\frac{p_{23}}
{q_{23}}$, $\frac{p_{23}}{q_{23}}<\frac{\operatorname{Card}\Omega}{K}<\frac{p_{21}}
{q_{21}}$ and $\frac{p_{23}}{q_{23}}=\frac{\operatorname{Card}\Omega}{K}$ and for each one we use $\frac{p}{q}<\frac{ap+bp'}{aq+bq'}<\frac{p'}
{q'}$

Comment: So we have $\operatorname{Card}\Omega=a\cdot p_{24}+b\cdot p_{23}$ or $\operatorname{Card}\Omega=b\cdot p_{23}+c\cdot p_{21}$ or $\operatorname{Card}\Omega=b\cdot p_{23}$ ($\operatorname{Card}\Omega\geq p_{23}$ in any case). Is it possible to improve? I don't know yet but I guess it is

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, All this comes from $\frac{p_{24}}{q_{24}}<\log_2(3)<\frac{p_{23}}{q_{23}}<\log_2(3+\frac{1}{662\cdot 2^{60}})<\frac{p_{21}}{q_{21}}$ and $\log_2(3)<\frac{\operatorname{Card}\Omega}{K}<\log_2(3+\frac{1}{662\cdot 2^{60}})$ ($\operatorname{Card}\Omega$ being the total length, and $K$ the number of odd steps)

Comment: Hmm, looking at the *generalized* convergent between $(p,q)_{22}$ and $(p,q)_{24}$ I find a smaller $N$ by which we should say: $\operatorname{Card} \Omega > gp_{22.2} = 114'208'327'604 (=S) $ For this smaller $N=6586818670$ (number of odd steps) we have $S/N \lt \rho$ where $\rho$ is your $\log_2()$-expression. - - - Maybe I'm not getting things correct still ...   (p.s. thanks for the explanations: it seems I can get now the inside idea! :-) )

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, In his argument, the "outer bounds" do not play a big role since the only common convergent is the $p_{23}$ and is the one that is "guaranteed". If you adjust with some tighter bounds on either side, it will only change the $b$ factor (which still is at least $1$). But I need to have a closer look, it is just a first thought I throw here, and is only about the minimum value of $\operatorname{Card}\Omega$

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, you were right. I thought this fraction would be part of the outer bounds and didn't pay enough attention. Thanks

Comment: Just for the record: the very first equation in this post is of Crandall, 1978 and might be better explained there; the deWeger/Simons-article (2010 version) does not explain the rationale of this (that is why I've skipped over it so far). The Crandall article is online available; one source is "Mathematics of Computation" Vol. 32

Comment: Indeed, the paper generalize Crandall to the m-cycles to give other bounds, which was not really used in my post. I had some hesitations, but I left the Simons reference because it has other interesting bounds